# What's the difference between defining these objects?

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between these?

```
var person = {
    age: 25,
    name: "David"
};

var person = (function() {
    var name = "David", age = 25;
}());
```

My question really is, what does `(function(){}())` do?

Comment: To me this is a very interesting topic. I found this website that gives some light on your question.

http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: And you are missing a quote from "David" I think

Comment: Both statements do totally different things, it does not make sense to compare them. The first one creates an object, the second one executes a function assignes the return value (`undefined`) to `person`.

Comment: @FelixKling: this should be the accepted answer. I wish I've seen your comment (or better read the question) before submitting [a wrong one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11927787/1081234)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**What does `(function(){}())` do?**

This essentially creates an anonymous function and then executes it. One common use for this is limiting global variables.

For example, the following would have three global variables (`var1`, `var2`, and `var3`):

```
var var1 = "a", var2 = "b", var3 = "c";
```

If you wrapped these declarations in the anonymous function, they're still accessible as local variables within the anonymous function, yet do not cloud up the global namespace. For example:

```
(function() {
    var var1 = "a", var2 = "b", var3 = "c";
    console.log(var1); // interact with local variables
})(); // execute function.
```

---

**What's the difference between these?**

```
var person = {
    age: 25,
    name: "David"
};
```

If this code is contained in a function, it creates a local variable named `person`. Otherwise, it creates a global variable named `person`.

```
var person = (function() {
    var name = "David", age = 25;
}());
```

This code creates and executes an anonymous function, then assigns the return code of that anonymous function to the variable `person`. Since the anonymous function has no return value, the variable `person` has a value of `undefined`. This statement, as it currently stands, is functionally equivalent to `var person;`, because the anonymous function has no side-effects and doesn't have a return value.

Comment: say there were methods in both the object literal and the anonymous function, i.e. getName().  I can still access person.getName() from either declaration.. so do both code ultimately achieve the same thing?

Comment: @anonymous - Unless an object was somehow returned in the anonymous function, you couldn't use `person.getName()`, so they're not really the same. If you want to use `person.getName()` from the anonymous function version, you could use this: `var person = (function() { this.getName = function() { return "Bob" }; return this; })();`

Answer (score 4):

```
var person = (function() {
    var name = "David", age = 25;
}());
```

person will be `undefined`, because the function doesn't have a `return` statement.

It is just a self executing anonymous function, you could image that as below.

```
function foo() {
  var name = "David", age = 25;
}
var person = foo();
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `undefined` value of the variable when the `new` keyword is not used with the constructor

Answer (score 2):

It executes the anonymous function you just created.

This technique is useful because it allows you to scope member in your class.

If you're looking for a good way to do classes and inheritance, take a look at http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

I'd also recommend defining your classes as AMD modules.

Comment: What does an immediate executed function have to do with "classes"? I agree, it is useful for scoping, but I don't see why you bring in classes.

Comment: @Felix Kling Just going by the title of the question. He's trying to define objects... Might as well talk about classes.

Comment: I don't see how it can be used with constructor functions and which benefit it brings. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Felix Kling Admittedly I know little about JS. But a constructor function feels a lot like a class definition to me. At least in the Java sense of class. Excpet for the "type" part of it of course. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, constructor functions create objects, but this has nothing to do with immediately executed functions, i.e. the construct `(function() {...}())`, and that's what the question is actually about (as far as I can tell at least).

Comment: The OP's example isn't a constructor unless the code is changed to use `new` when calling the function - in which case it still wouldn't do the same thing as the object literal because creating variables with `var` inside the function does not add them as properties to the returned object.